# How to convert Any to Dictionary in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I use Alamofire Network request,want to handling error messages,

My code :

```
class NetWorkingEngine: NSObject {
    typealias CreateNetWorkBlockSuccess = (_ responseobject:Any) -> ();
    typealias CreateNetWorkBlockFail = (_ responseobject:NSDictionary) -> ();

    func getDataFun(URL:String,netWorkingBlockSuccess:@escaping CreateNetWorkBlockSuccess,netWorkingBlockField:@escaping CreateNetWorkBlockField) -> Void {
        Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON { (responseObject) in
            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                netWorkingBlockSuccess(responseObject.data!);
            }else{
                netWorkingBlockFail(responseObject.result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in line

`netWorkingBlockFail(responseObject.result)`

error

`cannot convert value of type “Result<Any>” to expected argument type "NSDictionary"`

what should I do?

update:

`I want to  resquert Error Info, if you error request,Error info is 'Any',But how to 'Error info' convert Dictionary?`

Comment: try 
if let dictResult: NSDictionary = response.result.value as! NSDictionary { }

Comment: `response.result.value = nill` I don't need value ,but dictResult: NSDictionary = response.result as! NSDictionary error with `Cast from ‘Result<Any>’ to unrelated type ‘NSDicttionary’ always fails`

Comment: The question has nothing to do with Alamofire.

Comment: Yep,How to convert Any to Dictionary?

Answer (score 12):

You can convert Any type to Dictionary using [:] type. Suppose you have a variable called `person` which is of type Any; then use the following code:

```
let personDictionary = (person as! [String:String])["name"]
```

...where `name` is the key in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can only convert something to a Dictionary if it's in the form <**key: value**>.
The key must be a `Hashable` type to ensure that the key is unique.

To better understand the issue, play around with this in an Xcode playground project:

```
let str: Any = ""
testConvert(str)

let dict = ["one": 1, "two": 2]
testConvert(dict)

func testConvert(_ something: Any) {
    guard let dict = something as? [AnyHashable: Any] else {
        print("\(something) couldn't be converted to Dictionary")
        return
    }
    print("\(something) successfully converted to Dictionary")
}
```

Prints:

couldn't be converted to Dictionary

["one": 1, "two": 2] successfully converted to Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

mySelf Code

In NetWorkingTool.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
class NetWorkingTool: NSObject {
    static let shendInstance = NetWorkingTool()
    private override init() {}

    public func getData(url: String, dataBlock:@escaping (_ resData: Any) ->(), errorBlock:@escaping (_ error: Error) -> ()) -> Void {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (responseData) in
            if let json = responseData.result.value {
                dataBlock(json)
            }else{
                errorBlock(responseData.error!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NetWorkingTool.shendInstance.getData(url: "you url", dataBlock: { (responseData) in
          guard responseData is [AnyHashable: Any] else{
            print("\(type(of: responseData))")
            let dataArray = responseData as! Array<Any>
            for dict in dataArray {
                let d = dict as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                print(d["title"]!)
            }
            return
        }
        print("\(type(of: responseData))")
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forced unwrapping will crash your app if the conversion cannot be made:

let data = responseData as! NSArray 

Use conditional unwrapping instead. It gives you the possibility to handle the error if it occurs.

Example:

guard let data = responseData as? Array else { ... handle the error and return }

Comment: In case of JSON a Swift dictionary is always `[String:Any]`, not `[AnyHashable: Any]`. And instead unspecified `Array<Any>` (aka `[Any]`) write `[[String:Any]]`. This avoids the extra cast (in each iteration) to `Dictionary`.